# How to set an interval pause when applying the Shimmer effect in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

Using this cool package [Shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer), I want to play the shimmer effect after an interval pause, so is not back to back. I am using a variable with Timer.period but cannot get it to sync. (e.g. it will sometimes stop mid or near the end of the shimmer and ruin the effect).

Note, I also tried this package [shimmer_animation](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer_animation) which provides the option to set intervals, but unfortunately, this seemed to just allow for a shimmer effect over a given area, rather than just on a CustomPainter widget (which I am using).

```
  bool _shimmerEnabled = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), (Timer t) {
      _shimmerEnabled = !_shimmerEnabled;
      setState(() {});
    });
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: primaryColor,
          highlightColor: Colors.white,
          enabled: _shimmerEnabled,
          child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: 
///etc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following fork of package by jinyus, he has added functionality for delay between shimmers.

```
shimmer:
  git: 
     url: https://github.com/jinyus/flutter_shimmer
```

for more details https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_shimmer/issues/30#issuecomment-756565053